# Angular2: about duplicated declarations of Template Reference Variable in a template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I've found some problem of using a Template Reference Variables in a template.

When I declare identical template reference variables on a root level like the below, then the runtime compiler throws errors.

example>

```
 <input type="text" id="n-1" #myInput />
 <input type="text" id="n-2" #myInput />
```

However, when duplicated template reference variables are declared as a sub node, then there is no problem.

example>

```
 <div>
   <input type="text" id="n-1" #myInput />
   <input type="text" id="n-2" #myInput />
 </div>
```

Here is example code: https://embed.plnkr.co/kqTXfh/

I found that Angular Compiler checks the duplication of declaration of template reference variables.

This is the duplication check function code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L179-L196

In summary, my question is that can I use duplicated template reference variables in a sub node?

Is this expected result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late response. Although responding in case someone comes to this page wondering the same.

As per Official documentation **don't define the same variable name more than once in the same template as the runtime value will be unpredictable.**.

https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope